# How is memory allocated in this line of code "int **v = new int*[n]; "?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory-management, syntax

```
 int **v = new int*[n];
```

I'm confused as to what this does? could someone please explain?

Comment: Do you know what this does: `int *v = new int[n];`?  If you do, then what issue are you having with the line in your question?

Comment: Prefer [C++ containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container), e.g. `std::array` or `std::vector`. Read also http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This allocates an array of `n` pointers to `int`. A pointer to the first element in this array of pointers is stored in `v`. It is a double pointer, such that accessing an element via `v[i]` returns a stored pointer from the array.

Comment: You might also want to mention that the `n` pointers in the array are *uninitialised*.  This means that even accessing their values gives undefined behaviour.   To use them (e.g. even compare the pointers with other pointers, let alone dereference the pointers as if they point at the first element of an array) it is necessary to initialise them appropriately.

Comment: for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    matrix[i] = new int[n];
  }   This is a must have to use the above data structure

Comment: Better use `size_t` instead of `int` for `i`.

Answer (score 0):

it's not correctly complete:

```
int **v = new int*[n];
```

we'd think this means to allocates dynamically array of integer array on memory, so the dimension must suit it

statically equivalent

```
const size_t n=5;
int *v[n] = {} ;
```

// or
    int v[][n] ={ {1,2,3,4,5}, {6,7,8}, {9,8,7,6,5} }; //2 dimensional array

as max size of first dimension is inferred automatically to be 3 but
I guess IMHO, this is not yet given,

> int **v = new int*[n];

so it'd be specified as

```
int **v = new int*[n * 3];
```

Comment: You mean `int v[][n] =`